# How to run in background Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, email, background

Sending email with Laravel takes time before it is successfully sent, or sometimes it even fails. For this reason I would like to store record in database first and running email sending in background to save user's time. After storing the record, I would like to quickly redirect / refresh the page.

How do I use queue in below email sending code?

```
$message = new Applyonline($post_title, $cand_name);
$message->attachData($pdf->output(), $attach_name);
Mail::to($to_email)->send($message);
```

Please advise how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel Queues for this use the following link for complete explanation

[Queue Thorough Explaination](http://laravelcoding.com/blog/laravel-5-beauty-sending-mail-and-using-queues)

Comment: Firstly, do i have to run php artisan queue:table and php artisan migrate ?

Comment: Yes this will create a table jobs in your db. And when you do like Mail::queue you will see a record created in that table.

Comment: @PratikPowar Try this link - https://appdividend.com/2017/12/21/laravel-queues-tutorial-example-scratch/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into queues. Implementing this is quite easy. Just setup a queue for sending the mail and then add the queue to the mail facade. i.e `Mail::to()->queue(new MailQueue);`

[Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues)

[Queueing mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#queueing-mail)